# SwiftUI: Can't modify passed object

Tags: swiftui

I'm a beginner working on an app using the MVVM model. The basic idea is that I have Events that each contain several sessions. The events need to be able to be modified including adding and deleting sessions from the events. The main problem is that I can not modify a passed object as described below.

My model:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Event: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let trackName: String
    let date: Date
    var sessions: [Session]
}

struct Session: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let sessionNumber: Int
    let time: Date
}
```

I then have a View Model file that publishes the array of Events :

```
import Foundation

class EventListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // exposed variables
    @Published var events: [Event] = []
    
    var session1 = Session(sessionNumber: 1, time: Date.now)
    var session2 = Session(sessionNumber: 2, time: Date.now)
    
    init() {
        getEvents()
    }
    
    func getEvents() {
        let newEvents = [
            Event(trackName: "Awesome Event", date: Date.now, sessions: [session1, session2]),
            Event(trackName: "Second Event", date: Date.now, sessions: [session1, session2]),
            Event(trackName: "Latest Event", date: Date.now, sessions: [session1, session2]),
        ]
        events.append(contentsOf: newEvents)
    }
```

I then have an EventsListView that works as expected. Because "EventListViewModel" is observable, I can set it as an environment object in my View. And because "events" is published, I can access it in the View. So far so good.

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventsListView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var eventListViewModel: EventListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List{
                ForEach(eventListViewModel.events) { event in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EventDetailView(event: event), label: {
                        EventCell(event: event)
                    })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: eventListViewModel.deleteEvent)
                .onMove(perform: eventListViewModel.moveEvent)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Events")
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: EditButton(),
                trailing: NavigationLink("New Event", destination: AddEventView())
            )
        }
    }
}
```

When you click on the event in this List, it opens another view where you can see the details of the event. That works fine. The problem is that I can read the "session" variable, but I cannot append to it. I cannot modify it. "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable"

```
mport SwiftUI

struct EventDetailView: View {
    
    //@EnvironmentObject var eventListViewModel: EventListViewModel
    
    var event: Event
    
    var body: some View {
        //NavigationView {
        VStack {
                Text(event.trackName)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
             
                Text("Number of Sessions: \(event.sessions.count)")
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Sessions")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading )
                    
                    Text("Add Session")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            //eventListViewModel.addSession(event: event)
                            var newSession = Session(sessionNumber: event.sessions.count+1, time: Date.now)
                            //event.sessions.append(newSession) // <-THIS DOES NOT WORK
                        }
                }
            

                ForEach(event.sessions) { session in
                    
                        SessionCell(session: session)  // <-THIS WORKS
                    
                }
```

In the Event model, I set the sessions variable to a var.. I understand there is some concept where when you pass an object, it is read only. How should I set this up so that I can modify the sessions? I haven't actually gotten to this point yet, but I also need to be able to modify the Events. What's the proper way to organize this?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE------

I've implemented your suggestion, except I can't get the EventView preview to work. I've done this and it errors saying "Cannot convert value of type 'Event' to expected argument type 'Binding'".  I've tried all sorts of things and nothing seems to work. I tried including as an .environmentObject modifier, combos if local variables with Binding wrappers, etc. I can't crack it.

```
struct EventView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        
        Group {
            //EventView(eventIndex: 0)
            EventView( Event(name: "Event", track: "Motorsport Park", date: Date.now, notes: "", sessions: [Session(time: Date.now, bestLap: "1:32.5", setupSel: 0, tiresSel: 0, weather: "", notes: "")]) )
                .environmentObject(EventListViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a binding for your event, such as:

In `EventsListView` use this (note `$`):

```
ForEach($eventListViewModel.events) { $event in
    NavigationLink(destination: EventDetailView(event: $event), label: {
        ...
    }
```

and in `EventDetailView`, use this:

```
struct EventDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var eventListViewModel: EventListViewModel
    @Binding var event: Event  // <-- here
```

EDIT-1: try something like this for your `EventView_Previews` problem

```
struct EventView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var event = Event(name: "Event", track: "Motorsport Park", date: Date.now, notes: "", sessions: [Session(time: Date.now)])
    
    static var previews: some View  {
        Group {
            EventView(event: $event)
                .environmentObject(EventListViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming your `EventView` is something like this:

```
struct EventView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var eventListViewModel: EventListViewModel
    @Binding var event: Event
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I decided that rather than pass "event" to the following view, I should just access the same object throughout my program as an EnvironmentObject. So in this section of code, I now just pass the array index of that particular Event from the array of Events. I'm also using NavigationViews so I can attach the env object to it and it carries through the other views. Seems to be working so far. Thanks again

Comment: Note that passing array index around is not considered good practice, neither is using EnvironmentObject for this. But if that is what you have decided, good luck.

Comment: I'd certainly like to learn the best way. My top level object is an array of Events. As I move deeper into the Navigation Views I go from list of Events, to one of the Events, to one of the Sessions that are in an Event. I wonder how I can identify the one I want to view then?  I picked up the 'environment object gets inherited from top level NavigationView' thing from "Hacking with Swift", here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui

Comment: your code plus my solution to your question, is the "best" way in my humble opinion.

Comment: Ok, I've implemented it using your way. I guess stepping back, it makes more sense to pass an "event" to the event view than it does an index of an environment object. Much more direct. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, its mostly implemented. It all seems to be ok except for the preview. I added code to the original post. Can you please advise? Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution for your `EventView_Previews`